# Create a frame for content without images/bg

Tags: html, css

I have a background that is a set of fairly complex gradients (done with CSS, not images).  In the middle of the page is a fixed frame, and the content sits inside this frame.  I can set `overflow-y: auto` on this frame to scroll the content, but I would like to be able to use the window to scroll instead.

Here is what the page looks like now:

[image]

I would like the scroll bar to be on the window instead.  I can take the content outside of the frame and add margins as necessary, but the problem is that then the content will appear outside the frame.  I could then cover it up on the top and bottom, but this is difficult/impossible because the background is not an image and is not solid.

Is there any way to have a transparent element at the top/bottom block text that scrolls under it?  Can you somehow apply styles to content that overlaps?

Even the fanciest single-browser only solution that requires JavaScript is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

if all you're aiming at is hiding the scrollbar (and assuming you're ok with jQuery), i'd suggest to use something like [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll).

what's going on under the hood is simple: the designated container is assigned with `overflow: hidden;`, and attached with a hover handler - with the sole purpose of simulating a custom scrollbar in response to mouse-over events.

Comment: Sounds like it would work.  I'd really like to avoid intense JavaScript (and jQuery at all) in this thing, but if there's no other option I will yield.

Comment: i concur. adding jQuery for a specific task seem an overkill, but i see no way you can achieve this using CSS alone. i hope i'll be proven false - i'd love to hear about a pure CSS solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) features. 
It's powerfull flexible JQuery plugin for working with scrollbars, possibly you will find solution with it.